# WCF service contract not working with Microsoft Chart control as param

Tags: wcf

I have the following service contract:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Print(Chart chart);
}
```

When I run attempt to host the service (in Visual Studio under the WCFTestClient) I get the following exception:

`Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.`

It seems to be an issue with the `Chart` type itself as changing this to something else works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to the Chart type not being serializable.

Try sending over an object containing the chart data instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the Chart Serializer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartserializer(VS.100).aspx

It helps handle the serialization for you, which I suspect is probably the reason why you may be getting the message posted.